# A Custom ComboBox Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I am trying to create a custom style for a WPF ComboBox but whenever I do, the drop down does not open, I want to use the following XAML Code created from my buttons style but port it to work with a ComboBox Control, how would I go about doing this so that the dropdown does show and will give me the ability to change the mouseover colours.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
    <Border Name="border" 
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
            CornerRadius="1" 
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <!--TODO: Set the right colors-->
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFC6C6C6" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF666666" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFCCCCCC"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: What is your goal? Is it to make the ComboBox toggel button have the same style as other buttons in your app or to add mouseover colors to each ComboBoxItem? If the latter, you can do this by just styling the items themselves.

Comment: Otherwise, I recommend looking at the default ComboBox control template and modifying what you need to as it is a much more complex control than a button: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I would like for the style control template above to be recoded to work with a combobox, including the border etc. If there's an easier way to remove the blue mouseover color then please be my guest

Comment: @crazyarabian: The template on that page is an example of what a template might look like and not the default.

Comment: @H.B.: thanks for clarifying that; I guess I wasn't paying close enough attention

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ComboBoxes are rather complex, if you change one aspect of the ControlTemplate like those triggers you would need to supply all of the other functionality as well, your best bet might be copying the default template and adjusting it. The default templates can be found [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx) (see `Default WPF Themes` link).

Comment: That's great, was helpful and got me along my way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the appearance of the entire ComboBox control, the easiest thing to do is start with the [original template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx) and modify it to meet your needs. To change how items are highlighted, you need to reset the HighlightBrushKey value. Hopefully this resource is helpful: http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=26

Answer (score 1):

You may try this template and edit it the way you want.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d">
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border
          x:Name="Border" 
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          CornerRadius="0"
          Background="#FF535353"
          BorderBrush="#FF535353"
          BorderThickness="0" />
            <Border 
          Grid.Column="0"
          CornerRadius="0,0,0,0" 
          Margin="1" 
          Background="#FF323232" 
          BorderBrush="#FF535353"
          BorderThickness="3,0,0,0" />
            <Path 
          x:Name="Arrow"
          Grid.Column="1"     
          Fill="#3a3a3a"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="DarkGray" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Height="30" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" />
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="CmoboboxStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton 
                    Name="ToggleButton" 
                    Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                    Grid.Column="2" 
                    Focusable="false"
                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                    ClickMode="Press">
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <ContentPresenter
                        Name="ContentSite"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                        Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                        Margin="8,0,0,0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                        Style="{x:Null}" 
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                        Focusable="True" 
                        Background="Transparent"
                        Visibility="Hidden"
                        Foreground="DarkBlue"
                        IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                        <Popup 
                        Name="Popup"
                        Placement="Bottom"
                        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                        AllowsTransparency="True" 
                        Focusable="False"
                        PopupAnimation="Slide">
                            <Grid 
                          Name="DropDown"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                          MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                          MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                <Border 
                                x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                Background="#FF323232"
                                BorderThickness="4,0,0,0"
                                BorderBrush="#FF535353"/>
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="4,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEditable"
           Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: how do we style the combobox dropdown? like change the padding of the combobox items?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to override the default ComboBox template to get it to work properly (see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250622/mouseover-highlighting-style-returning-to-default-after-a-second-caused-by-aero) post).

Do you have access to [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx)? You can use it to extract and edit control templates. I find it very useful to [edit](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294908)/[create](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc263912) templates.

[Show Me the Templates](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/Posts/Details/2091) is another tool to view control templates.