# WPF combobox (non-dropdown item) highlight on mouseover

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have a combobox that highlights to a whitish color when I mouse over it. I want to change the color of this mouse over highlighting. I have looked at many solutions on this site, but they all seems to do with the drop-down items themselves. I'm trying to change the highlighting color of the combobox before I even click on it to expose the dropdown.

Comment: I found that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610339/combobox-mouseover) which might give you the answer of your problem

Comment: Good stuff, but seems pretty complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `ComboBoxItem` style and change the color of MouseOver in trigger.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Border 
          Name="Border"
          Padding="2"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
          <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundBrush}"/>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource <<Your Static Brush color key>>"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm not trying to set the color of the comboboxitem. I'm trying to set the highlightcolor of the combobox itself on mouse over.